# How this specific DNS configuration works?

Tags: bind, dns-zone

Recently, a partner asked us to do following in one of our DNS zones:

```
_dmarc.send.domain.com. TXT "v=DMARC1; p=none"
send.domain.com.        NS  ns1.otherdomain.com.
send.domain.com.        NS  ns2.otherdomain.com.
```

`otherdomain.com` DNS define an MX record for `send`

To my surprise this worked and both `_dmarc.send.domain.com.` (TXT) and `send.domain.com` (MX).

**How is this possible?**

---

**Some thoughts about root zones:**

I know in root zones, for example .COM, domains are defined in similar matter (I did simplified the output):

```
dig google.com ns @a.gtld-servers.net.

google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.

ns2.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns1.google.com.     172800  IN  A   216.239.32.10
```

However, if `ns1.google.com` and `ns2.google.com` stops working, query like this **MAY** stop working as well (I assume I have locan DNS server at localhost):

```
dig google.com ns @127.0.0.1
```

It may stop, because local DNS server will ask `ns1.google.com` or `ns2.google.com` for the information.

---

**Some thoughts about "uploading" hosts in the root zones:**

This is precisely, why setting DNS as `www.domain.com` will not work. Let me elaborate about it:

Some .com registrars allow you to set single DNS server (instead of two). Then you register a domain - `domain.com`, then you set DNS on your domain - `www.domain.com` and on your web server, you put DNS server as well.

Now, if someone visits your website, theoretically, the DNS query is handle from the root .COM server.

Except this does not work. Or let be precise - most of the time, the DNS query go to your DNS server anyway and if your local DNS stops working, most of the clients can not resolve  name `www.domain.com`.

Comment: You may want to read about glue records and other DNS terminology RFC 8499.

Comment: I know about glue records, but it is not 100 percent reliable I think. My understanding is, if the client know about ns1.otherdomain.com, the TXT may be not visible, unless same TXT is set in ns1.otherdomain.com (which is not)

Comment: You are not describing the issue clearly. In the question you are talking about NS servers not working but now in the comment you are talking about inconsistent RR between glue data and the authoritative zone. These are different situations.

Comment: if I do `send.domain.com.        NS  ns1.otherdomain.com.`, then authoritative zone go to `ns1.otherdomain.com`. The "glue" record `_dmarc.send.domain.com` should be in the authoritative zone, but is not. So this is inconsistency and should not work in 100% of the cases. I am asking if I am correctly understand the situation.

Comment: Your phrasing is a bit unclear in "should not work in 100% of the cases". Do you expect this configuration to fail in 100% of cases or just in some cases? What exactly surprises you?

Comment: well, this depends of what DNS server was used - if was easy to understand, I would check google or chat gpt.